# How to find rows in ms-sql with another rows' value followingly?

Tags: sql-server, loops, sorting, common-table-expression

I have created an Sql table to trace objects' operation history. I have two columns; first one is the self tracing code and second tracing code is the tracing code for the code coming from source object to target. I created this to be able to look up the route of operations through the objects. You can see the tracing sample table below:

[image]

I need to create an sql code to query to show all the route in one table. When I first select the self code, it will be the incoming code for previous rows. There may be more than one incoming code to self and I want to be able to trace all. And I want to reach end until my search is null.

I tried select query like below but I am so new sql and need your help.

```
SELECT [TracingCode.Self],
       [TracingCode.Incoming],
       [EquipmentNo]
FROM [MKP_PROCESS_PRODUCT_REPORTS].[dbo].[ProductionTracing.Main]
WHERE [TracingCode.Self] = (SELECT [TracingCode.Incoming]
                            FROM [MKP_PROCESS_PRODUCT_REPORTS].[dbo].[ProductionTracing.Main]
                            WHERE [TracingCode.Self] = (SELECT [TracingCode.Incoming]
                                                        FROM [MKP_PROCESS_PRODUCT_REPORTS].[dbo].[ProductionTracing.Main]
                                                        WHERE [TracingCode.Self] = (SELECT [TracingCode.Incoming]
                                                                                    FROM [MKP_PROCESS_PRODUCT_REPORTS].[dbo].[ProductionTracing.Main]
                                                                                    WHERE [TracingCode.Self] = '028.001.19.2.3')));
```

Comment: Well... what does your output look like? Is there a maximum number of hops? This type of thing is typically solved with a CTE. Please post your closest attempt so we don't repeat your efforts.

Comment: _I tried many different select query_ Great, but you need to show what did you try, so please edit your question and include the query.

Comment: For example, perhaps as output you want a two column table. The first column is the tracing code and the second one is an ordinal number indicating the order

Comment: I added my primitive code.

Comment: Please have a think about what output you want.

Comment: I want an output with same columns but only found results, only linked rows first column including following rows second column. I want to do something like recursive function in c coding.

Comment: OK now I understand - you want exactly the same dataset but limited to one route. Let me have a think. A CTE will be involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this kind of parent/child thing to any level without explicitly coding all levels you need to use a **recursive CTE.**

More details here

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/

Here is some test data and a solution I came up with. Note that *three* records actually match `028.001.19.2.3`

If this doesn't do what you need please explain further with sample data.

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE  (
TC_Self CHAR(14) NOT NULL, 
TC_In CHAR(14) NOT NULL, 
EquipmentNo INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Sample (TC_Self, TC_In, EquipmentNo)
VALUES 
('028.001.19.2.3','026.003.19.2.2',96),
('028.001.19.2.3','026.001.19.2.2',96),
('028.001.19.2.3','026.002.19.2.2',96),
('028.001.19.2.2','026.002.19.2.1',96),
('028.001.19.2.2','026.002.19.2.1',96),
('028.001.19.2.1','026.002.19.1.1',96),
('026.003.19.2.2','024.501.19.2.5',117),
('024.501.19.2.5','024.501.19.2.6',999),
('024.501.19.2.6','024.501.19.2.7',998);


WITH CTE (RecordType, TC_Self, TC_In, EquipmentNo)
AS
(
-- This is the 'root'
SELECT 'Root' RecordType, TC_Self, TC_In, EquipmentNo FROM @Sample
WHERE TC_Self = '028.001.19.2.3'
UNION ALL

SELECT 'Leaf' RecordType, S.TC_Self, S.TC_In, S.EquipmentNo FROM @Sample S
INNER JOIN CTE 
ON S.TC_Self = CTE.TC_In 
)

SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Also please note that most of the time to generate this answer was taken in generating the sample data to use.

In future when asking questions, **people are far more likely to help if you post this sample data generation yourself**

Comment: Nick.McDermaid I achieved finally with your help! Thank you.